# Is XP spent at character creation treated the same as • spending?

Tags: character-creation, chronicles-of-darkness-1e

Say, as a crude example (I don't fact-check points costs atm on my phone) I have a character who buys:

Giant ••••
Encyclopedic knowledge ••
Fleet of foot •

And as he has some starting XP he decides to buy:
Eidetic Memory •• (NB purchase only allowed at character creation)

Ignoring when altering the order of buying would circumvent this, can starting XP be used this way, or have I imagined 'At Character Creation only' -> Bought with • only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Not according to the rules as written.**

Characters starting with Experience Points is an optional rule, called **Advanced Characters**. This rule states that:

> For more experienced characters, the Storyteller might choose to award
>   Experience Points that may be spent before play begins.

Therefore, while a starting character normally would only apply the normal [character creation rules](http://www.thesubnet.com/portal/wod2/wod2.0/index.html), an advanced character would then also add experience according to the [experience table](http://www.thesubnet.com/portal/wod2/wod2.0/RolePlayEP.html).

This means that Since a character has no experience points during character creation, anything which can only be taken during character creation can not be bought with experience points. Any experience that the character has at the start of the game is then spent *after* character creation, and *before* play begins.

However, I have played in some games where the Storyteller has allowed the use of experience points to purchase those abilities normally restricted to character creation. So, while the rules say no, it is not uncommon to ignore them in this case.

Comment: I say that the rules as written don't cover the area sufficiently well, and that the Storyteller needs to fill in the gap, as she should once the decision to add extra XP is made.

Comment: @Jadasc I re-wrote my answer. I feel I have addressed all the concerns, let's remove these comments.

Answer (score 3):

**It's a Storyteller call.**

The "Advanced Characters" optional rule is what gives you the additional starting XP. Although the rules-as-written place the "add XP" step in a weird limbo between character creation and "before play begins"--which would imply "no"--an ST willing to let you start with extra experience points probably has an opinion as to whether you can take "at creation" merits with them.

The *God Machine Chronicle* takes it a step further by making many fewer of the merits "At Creation Only." In your case, it's Giant and that's it.

Comment: This a very good answer, but I feel inbar's covers the RAW and RAI better.