# If I don't spend all of my starting XP 'before play starts,' does it get wiped out?

Tags: character-creation, chronicles-of-darkness-1e

In [a previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/35800/is-xp-spent-at-character-creation-treated-the-same-as-spending),  an answer quotes the rules on starting XP. It states that it can be spent *before play starts*.

Taken literally, which may not be the intention, it means I cannot spend this XP at all, ever, after we start the game.

Is this the intention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [the accepted answer of that Q](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/35801/507), that XP is regular XP that you *may* spend whenever you wish (though your ST may require you to spend it at character creation, obviously.)

Witness the use of "may" instead of "may only/must/should/can only/etc":

> For more experienced characters, the Storyteller might choose to award
>   Experience Points that may be spent before play begins.

Disallowing spending the XP later, which is otherwise a valid character building option (saving your XP for more costly improvements), would unbalance the game, which is not likely to be intended either by the designers or the ST. Nonetheless, again, consult your ST (or make up your mind about the issue, taking the above into consideration, if you're the ST. :))

Answer (score 2):

The intent of the advanced characters option is to allow players to have characters that have some measure of experience under their belts before the chronicle starts. Although it's possible to save some of the XP for later -- 10 being a popular limit -- it's considered something of a breach of etiquette in practice. The goal is to produce more developed characters at game start, rather than get a jump on stockpiling for the next 5-dot or boost in Gnosis or Blood Potency.